# How to export a single band raster to an ascii XYZ file in QGIS 3.14?

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

In QGIS 3.14 , how can I export a raster (GeoTIFF) file as a XYZ formatted textfile, like;

```
Lon      Lat     z
123.456  34.567  23.45
123.447  34.588  20.22
...      ...     ...
```

Seems I have two options to export (save) raster files:

1. Mouse 'Right-click' on the layer to activate the context menu and choose  `Export > Save As...`
2. From `Raster` menu, choose `Translate (Convert Format)` which is equivalent to the *GDAL Translate* in the Processing Toolbox.

The first option offers me lots of export formats - (*below image*) - but I cannot figure out which one returns simple ascii xyz textfiles.

[image]

With the second option, I can modify GDAL command call (to add `-of XYZ`) like I did in QGIS 2.18, but unfortunately QGIS 3.14 does not allow me to remove pre-existing `-of GTiff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output type option is inferred from the extension of the filename you specify for output. If you change the name to end in `.xyz` then the `-of` option in the GDAL line will change and you can save in XYZ format:

[image]

which gave me:

```
3.125 2.83333333333333348 1
3.375 2.83333333333333348 4
3.625 2.83333333333333348 7
3.875 2.83333333333333348 10
3.125 2.5 2
3.375 2.5 5
3.625 2.5 8
3.875 2.5 11
3.125 2.16666666666666696 3
3.375 2.16666666666666696 6
3.625 2.16666666666666696 9
3.875 2.16666666666666696 12
```

for my test 3x4 raster. I didn't get any column headings, maybe additional options can add them if you need them.

Comment: Forgot to say the header is not important. Thanks!

Comment: if you want one I think it's -co ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES

Comment: @nmtoken Yes, `-co ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES` gave me  **X Y Z** as the topmost line. Thanks!